# How precisely to create a dependency property that can be assigned in a user control

Tags: c#, xaml, dependency-properties, win-universal-app

My attempts at reengaging with XAML in Universal Windows is making me hit a lot of brick walls, so here I am begging for help as nothing I've read seems to indicate I'm doing something wrong, so I must be missing something important.

I'm simply trying to create a custom Universal Windows user control that exposes some properties to the place where it is consumed.  However, when I try to assign those properties in XAML in the app that consumes the user control I get an error thrown "XamlParseException: Failed to assign to property."  I would be ever so grateful if someone helped me understand what I'm doing wrong and why it is that it is wrong.

So far, thankfully, the control isn't big as I'm having enough trouble getting it to work properly that it's not growing, so I'll post its entirety here - just trying to get a simple Hamburger Overlay User Control so I don't make a custom one for every app I do:

```
<UserControl
x:Class="POWU.Controls.HamburgerOverlay" x:Name="VM"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:POWU.Controls"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"

mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300"
d:DesignWidth="400">
    <SplitView PaneBackground="{x:Null}" OpenPaneLength="{x:Bind Path=ExpandSize, Mode=OneWay}" IsPaneOpen="True">
        <SplitView.Pane>
            <Grid Background="#7F000000"></Grid>
        </SplitView.Pane>
        <SplitView.Content>
            <Grid></Grid>
        </SplitView.Content>
    </SplitView>
</UserControl>
```

And the code behind:

```
namespace POWU.Controls
{        
    public sealed partial class HamburgerOverlay : UserControl
    {
        public double ExpandSize
        {
            get
            {
                return (double)GetValue(ExpandSizeProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(ExpandSizeProperty, value);
            }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ExpandSize.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ExpandSizeProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ExpandSize", typeof(double), typeof(HamburgerOverlay), new PropertyMetadata(200));

        public HamburgerOverlay()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }        
    }
}
```

EDIT: Here I'm adding the XAML that consumes the user control...

```
    <Grid>
        <po:HamburgerOverlay ExpandSize="300"></po:HamburgerOverlay>
    </Grid>
```

I'm thinking my problem is with the "PropertyMetadata" and needing a "DependencyPropertyCallback" - but I'm not sure exactly how to implement that.  Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT2:** I tried setting the property in code behind instead of XAML (should've tried this in the first place) and got a more specific exception:

```
 "Method not found: 'Void POWU.Controls.HamburgerOverlay.set_ExpandSize(Double)'."
```

With the stack trace:

```
   at PODebugging.MainPage..ctor()
   at PODebugging.PODebugging_XamlTypeInfo.XamlTypeInfoProvider.Activate_4_MainPage()
   at PODebugging.PODebugging_XamlTypeInfo.XamlUserType.ActivateInstance()
   at Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame.Navigate(Type sourcePageType, Object parameter)
   at PODebugging.App.OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
```

Now I'm really confused... how could a method just disappear?

Comment: Try looking at this example [C#](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/XamlBind/cs/MyUserControl1.xaml.cs), [XAML](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/XamlBind/cs/MyUserControl1.xaml). My guess is you have to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` for it to work.

Comment: Try add `this.DataContext = this;` under `this.InitializeComponent();` and `{Binding ExpandSize}` instead of `{x:Bind Path=ExpandSize, Mode=OneWay}`

Comment: @daniel I'd really prefer to figure out how to use compile-time binding.

Comment: You need DataContext being set for Binding, but I see no where you do this.

Comment: @daniel How do I set the DataContext to the UserControl class (i.e. the instance of HamburgerOverlay)?  I was of the view that this is handled automatically by x:Bind as it only allows you to use dependency properties of the owning class itself.

Comment: @daniel I'm pretty new to XAML, I tried it about a year ago and then moved on to a different project after getting seriously stuck - but with UWP I figured it's time for me to get off my lazy butt and seriously plow through learning it.  The hardest thing about it is it gives me non-specific errors, as I'm sure you know, so it's hard to self-diagnose what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @daniel Oh, sorry, I missed your codebehind for how to set the datacontext.  I tried that and no luck.  As long as I don't try to assign the property the binding works fine - the exception is only thrown when I try to set the property from the xaml that consumes the user control.

Comment: Sorry, no need to add the datacontext. BTW, how do you set the propery from the xaml that consumes the user control? By bind or constant? Show me the code, please.

Comment: @daniel I just added the code - I'm trying to set it by constant like you can do with normal controls.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer:

The first thing I needed to do was switch the build of my class library from x86 to "AnyCPU" - this cleared up issues of not finding properties even though I was building to x86 in both projects.

The second thing I needed to do, as much as I should have noticed it was fix the default value.  It was a stupid mistake, but it was making my binding confused:

This:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ExpandSizeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ExpandSize", typeof(double),
            typeof(HamburgerOverlay), new PropertyMetadata(200));
```

Needed to be changed to this:

```
 public static readonly DependencyProperty ExpandSizeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ExpandSize", typeof(double),
            typeof(HamburgerOverlay), new PropertyMetadata((double)200));
```

This should have been obvious if I were paying more close attention, but I wasn't.

Sigh.  Another brick wall climbed.  I'm sure I'll hit another in 10 minutes.

Comment: Just write `new PropertyMetadata(200.0)` or `new PropertyMetadata(200d)`.

Comment: @Clemens Hey, thanks... I didn't know you could use the "d" like that... the more you learn...  Weird basic stuff you somehow missed.

Comment: I hade the same issue with a x64 Build Setting - it really depends on the build setting